# Using Visual Basic to call an API

Tags: php, visual-studio-2010

im having a hard time trying to figure this out my problem. im trying to basically call an URL API in visual basic. like iv got a PHP file that deletes a file on a web server. id like to make a visual basic program buttons that I click and its like the equivalent of me typing like "www.website.com/delete.php?file=" but doesn't actually have to open a web-browser and type that in then close it. what id really like it to do if possible to also have it like return the result of it like it at the moment if deleted it will reply on the page in plain text "completed". so id like it to take that, store it in a variable so I can see what it will reply with.

so it needs to:

- be able to attach a string from a variable and apply it to the end of the URL
- do this silently as I find it is not very fast to have it open a web browser to do it then close it.(also looks ugly because of that)
- And if possible, take the text reply from the PHP script page and store it in a variable.

any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look at `HttpWebRequest`.

Comment: have you tried anything yet? It will roll better if you have some sample code.